# java bytebuffer slice not working as per documentation

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have been working with bytebuffers for a long time but seldom used slice. But now we have an big issue with `slice()` on `bytebuffer`.

Please see below code :

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        ByteBuffer original = ByteBuffer.wrap("234567".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        printBuffer("org: ",original);

        original.position(1);
        original.limit(original.limit()-2);

        printBuffer("org: ",original);


        ByteBuffer sliced =  original.slice();
        printBuffer("slc: ",sliced);

        ByteBuffer duplicated =  original.duplicate();
        printBuffer("dup: ",duplicated);

        ByteBuffer compact =  original.compact();
        printBuffer("cmp: ",compact); 
    }


    private static  void printBuffer(String prefix,ByteBuffer buff) 
    {
        System.out.println(prefix+buff);
        System.out.println(prefix+Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(buff.array(), buff.position(), buff.limit())));

    }

}
```

It results in

```
org: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6]
org: [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
org: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=1 lim=4 cap=6]
org: [51, 52, 53]
slc: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3]
slc: [50, 51, 52]
dup: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=1 lim=4 cap=6]
dup: [51, 52, 53]
cmp: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=3 lim=6 cap=6]
cmp: [53, 54, 55]
```

Please see slc: value in the above result. I would expect something like `[51, 52, 53]`.

Correct me If I am wrong.
is it a Bug in java ?

I tested this in java 7 , 8

Answer (score 6):

To add to m.antkowicz answer, the position is indeed `0`, but thanks to the `offset` property of the slice (that you can access using `buff.arrayOffset()`), using:

```
sliced.get(0);
```

will give you `51`. To print visualize this, change your `printBuffer` method to this:

```
private static void printBuffer(String prefix, ByteBuffer buff) {
    System.out.println(prefix + buff);
    System.out.print(prefix);
    for (int i = buff.position(); i < buff.limit(); i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + buff.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It will print:

```
org: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6]
org:  50 51 52 53 54 55
org: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=1 lim=4 cap=6]
org:  51 52 53
slc: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3]
slc:  51 52 53
dup: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=1 lim=4 cap=6]
dup:  51 52 53
cmp: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=3 lim=6 cap=6]
cmp:  53 54 55
```

To keep using `Arrays.asList`, add the `offset` to both the `position` and `limit` properties:

```
int offset = buff.arrayOffset();
Arrays.copyOfRange(buff.array(), buff.position() + offset, buff.limit() + offset)
```

Recall that under the hood, a `slice` shares the same underlying array as the original buffer. Only the `offset` property is changed, so that you can access a subportion of the buffer using different positions.

Comment: Thanks Evryone .I understood now .

Answer (score 3):

From the `slice` method [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice()):

> The new buffer's position **will be zero**, its capacity and its limit will be the number of bytes remaining in this buffer, and its mark will be undefined.

So although you set the position to `1` it works fine due to the documentation

Comment: and how about "The content of the new buffer will start at this buffer's current position" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `printBuffer` method is wrong: `slice` creates keeps internally an offset to access the underlying byte array.

To output the correct values from the underlying byte array, the `printBuffer` method also needs to use this offset:

```
private static  void printBuffer(String prefix,ByteBuffer buff) 
{
    System.out.println(prefix+buff);
    System.out.println(prefix+Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(buff.array(), buff.position()+buff.arrayOffset(), buff.limit()+buff.arrayOffset())));

}
```